# Is it okay to define a mathematical proposition in your own paper that's similar to that of another paper?

Tags: publications, mathematics

Suppose that another author has defined a proposition in a published paper. For the purposes of my own paper, I would like to use that proposition. However, I would have to re-define the proposition (e.g., simple algebraic manipulation). Is it okay for me to call this a proposition in my own work? Or should I cite the previous author's proposition and then describe the algebraic manipulation to get it to the form I want?

Comment: There isn't enough here to really give advice. What do you mean by "proposition"? What do you mean by "re-define"?  What do you mean by "similar"? But, if you have doubts, then it is better to cite than not.

Comment: You definitely need to cite the paper. It's OK to restate or slightly modify a thm/lemma/prop in your paper as long as you cite and it's clear the result is proved in the cited paper.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would say that the best way to do it depends a bit on the amount of manipulation needed. If it is short and obvious (e.g. mostly changing notation), a simple direct citation should suffice, if not you will have to describe it in more detail. But either way, you will have to cite the original author for academic integrity and you should state your version in full, for readability.

Thus I'd go with either something like "**Proposition 1** (adapted from [1, Prop. A])", followed by the the full statement of your version and no proof or alternatively the full statement of your version and a proof of the form "**Proof:** Take [1, Prop. A] and ..." followed by whatever needed to perform the transformation. There is also the rare case where writing down a changed proof is more readable than doing the transformation, in which case I would recommend doing so (but definitely keep the adapted from citation).

Answer (score 1):

Always obey the Golden Rule: Do what is is most helpful for the reader.

Thus, the more pertinent question here: Irrespective of what changes you are making, would it be helpful to your reader to have a citation to another paper telling them about the similar definition?

Comment: I would say that the Golden Rule of academic publishing is "always cite your sources". Poorly written papers might be forgiven; plagiarism will not be.

Comment: I am not suggesting plagiarism; in this case the OP refers to a situation where they are not convinced the reference is necessary.  Within that context, it might still be helpful for the reader.